# Remove .php using .htaccess and redirect to its non .php version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, browser

I have a website in which i need to remove every file´s .php extension, and then redirect any link pointing to any file containing a .php extension to the same file but without the .php.

I have found the following code. It is pretty useful, but anything contained in a folder is gonna be redirected to the root as shown in this example:

http://www.example.com/folder/file.php

redirects to

http://www.example.com/file (without the .php)

---

The code is this:

RewriteEngine On

```
#Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Redirect without .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Is this .htaccess inside `folder/` directory ?

Comment: No, it is not. I´ve placed it only within the root directory. Should I copy it to every folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rules with this one and retest **in a new browser** or completely clear your browser cache:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Now everything inside a folder redirects to the homepage, without any file name. Does not work either.

Comment: These rules are working on my live website to remove `.php` extension so there is nothing wrong with the rules.

Comment: sure, the .php removal works fine. But for any file inside a folder, when I click a link to it, it redirects me to the homepage.

a link to
example.com/folder/file.php

leads me to
example.com

Comment: `a link to example.com/folder/file.php leads me to example.com` is definitely not happening within these 2 rules I suggested. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess as well? Also test if there is any other .htaccess or rules in Apache server side config. Check your Apache version as well.