# Rewrite everything but specific part of URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this user-generated URL: `https://example.com/watch.php?name=I9an9O.mp4`

What I'm trying to achieve is to grab the part that is inbetween  `name=` and `.mp4` (ie. `I9an9O`)

And this is how I want the URL to look like: `https://example.com/I9an9O`

I have tried putting this code into `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /watch.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, I was only able to remove the part that was in front of `I9an9O` but not the extensions after `I9an9O`. I used this online Mod Rewrite Tool: https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

After using it, the result was: `https://example.com/I9an9O.mp4.html`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused by your wording. Why is the first one "user-generated"? It appears you have a file called `watch.php` and accepts a query string argument called `name`. I think you want to give users a short URL such as `example.com/ABC123` and have that `ABC123` be passed automatically to the `watch.php`, but without the `watch.php` appearing in the URL, is that correct? Your rule as written includes `\.html` and I don't understand what that is about. Can you clarify things by updating your question?

Comment: Sure.

The website is similar to streamable.com - people can upload their own videos and each video has its own unique URL. 

On my website, i have a file called `watch.php` this file then generates a unique url: `example.com/watch.php?name=abc123.mp4`. The .mp4 is actually included in URL.

I want to turn that "long" url into a short one such as `example.com/abc123`.

With my current rule, i can remove everything but the .mp4 and .html - i can also remove html, but not the dot before html.

Eg.: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.$ /watch.php?name=$1 [L]`

Comment: The problem that you are going to run into eventually is that Apache doesn't have a way to differentiate between `/abc123` and `/watch.php`. One [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897668/231316) is to take control of 404's away from Apache and process it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the link. 

I have tried to create a `test.php` and then add the ?name=abc123 - without .mp4 at the end. I was able to get to `/abc123` just fine. Firstly i would make a rule which would turn `test.php?name=abc123` into `/abc123.gg` by using this rule: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.gg$ /test.php?name=$1 [L]`. Then i would use these two to remove the .gg from the end of the url: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` & 
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.gg [NC,L]` and the end result was `example.com/abc123`.

Comment: _Firstly I would make a rule_  - **no**, unless you have existing URLs in the wild that you want to redirect. Otherwise, never tell the world that such URLs exist, always send people to `example.com/abc123`. If you have URLs that exist that people are aware of, you can add a rule in your config to redirect them, but I honestly wouldn't bother. If someone has a direct link, it isn't a big deal. Just going forward only tell people about your pretty URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /watch.php?name=$1 [L]
> ```

Not sure why you are matching URLs that end with `.html` when your URLs should look like `/I9an9O`.

You would need to do something like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^\w+$ watch.php?name=$0.mp4 [L]
```

`\w` is a shorthand character class that matches upper/lowercase letters, digits and underscores only. So won't match URLs that contain dots (to avoid conflicts with actual files like `watch.php`) or URLs that contain multiple path segments (folders). The problem with using the more generic regex `[^/]*` (as in your original example) is that it would potentially match `watch.php` as well, creating an endless loop.

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

You should be linking to URLs of the form `/I9an9O` in your HTML source.

If you are changing an existing URL structure then you will also need to redirect "old" requests of the form `/watch.php?name=I9an9O.mp4` to the new URL. This *redirect* will need to go before the above rewrite.

The complete `.htaccess` file would then be something like the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests to "/watch.php?name=<name>.mp4" to "/<name>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(\w+)\.mp4
RewriteRule ^watch\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite requests of the form "/<name>" to "watch.php?name=<name>.mp4"
RewriteRule ^\w+$ watch.php?name=$0.mp4 [L]
```

Where `%1` in the first `RewriteRule` is a backreference to the captured subpattern in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. the `I9an9O` part of `name=I9an9O.mp4`.

The `QSD` flag is necessary to *discard* the original query string from the request.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects before changing to a 301 (permanent) in order to avoid potential caching issues.